# Counting silkworm eggs with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to write a python script to count the number of silkworm eggs. Some of the images are really tiny and some have overlapping ellipses/circles which makes it a little difficult. I have tried the following approaches:

```
im = cv2.imread('eggs1.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
th, bw = cv2.threshold(hsv[:, :, 2], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
dist = cv2.distanceTransform(morph, cv2.DIST_L2, cv2.DIST_MASK_PRECISE)
borderSize = 75
distborder = cv2.copyMakeBorder(dist, borderSize, borderSize, borderSize, borderSize, 
                                cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT | cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED, 0)
gap = 10                                
kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2*(borderSize-gap)+1, 2*(borderSize-gap)+1))
kernel2 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(kernel2, gap, gap, gap, gap, 
                                cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT | cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED, 0)
distTempl = cv2.distanceTransform(kernel2, cv2.DIST_L2, cv2.DIST_MASK_PRECISE)
nxcor = cv2.matchTemplate(distborder, distTempl, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
mn, mx, _, _ = cv2.minMaxLoc(nxcor)
th, peaks = cv2.threshold(nxcor, mx*0.5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
peaks8u = cv2.convertScaleAbs(peaks)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(peaks8u, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
peaks8u = cv2.convertScaleAbs(peaks)    # to use as mask
for i in range(len(contours)):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[i])
    _, mx, _, mxloc = cv2.minMaxLoc(dist[y:y+h, x:x+w], peaks8u[y:y+h, x:x+w])
    cv2.circle(im, (int(mxloc[0]+x), int(mxloc[1]+y)), int(mx), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.drawContours(im, contours, i, (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('circles', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
gray = cv2.imread("eggs2.jpg", 0)

## threshold
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

## findcontours
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]


## filter by area
s1= 3
s2 = 20
xcnts = []
for cnt in cnts:
    if s1<cv2.contourArea(cnt) <s2:
        xcnts.append(cnt)

print("Dots number: {}".format(len(xcnts)))
```

and

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image4.jpg', 0)
seed_pt = (184,252)
fill_color = 50
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
for th in range(60, 120):
    prev_mask = mask.copy()
    mask = cv2.threshold(img, th, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    mask = cv2.floodFill(mask, None, seed_pt, fill_color)[1]
    mask = cv2.bitwise_or(mask, prev_mask)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
cv2.imshow('image',mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The countour finding was the closest but failed when images like [image: this one] are used. A few of these images include: [image: 1] , [image: 2]

Is there a better way to get accurate or close to accurate counts?

Comment: You will not get accurate counts with the first image. You can’t see all the eggs, you can’t count them all.

Comment: if you can't even count yourself with a given image then it's unlikely to find an algorithm that can.

Comment: That first image is a nightmare.  The contrast of the eggs is so close with other ones that I'm even making mistakes figuring out which ones are different.

Answer (score 1):

As people here (Cris Luengo, Micka, and rayryeng) mentioned the first image would be pretty tough to work with. However, I see one way around (not sure if it would work well, but hope so).

Eggs may come in different color, so using HSV/RGB threshold may not always work, or will always need tuning. I would recommend to try to work with edge detection algorithms. Specifically, have a look at Laplacian, Canny, and Sobel methods.

So basically, those methods look for drastic changes in color on the image. Let us consider Sobel operator it works  by convolution of respective masks and a sliding window along the image. This convolution gives a numeric differentiation of the region, so the more the color changes, the more is the output of the operator. If you want, you can threshold it to get binary image.

[image: Example of Sobel operator on Lena]

Having the binary image you can play with morphology of it to reduce noise and improve quality of the image. If it works well, you can get closed contours of eggs, which will be more or less countable.

This approach is of course boils down to similar approach as HSV/RGB thresholding, but may be useful in counting overlaying eggs.

If you have a lot (literally a lot) of time and data to work with, you may want to use Machine Learning (HOG+SVM, RCNN etc.). But this will need a lot of data and time to do.

Good luck!